# Twig debugging does not work

Tags: 9

I tried to enable twig debugging, to be able to use `{{dump(var)}}`
I followed the drupal docs exactly.
Copy the default.services.yml, Change the copy it's name into services.yml. And set debug on true.

When I click on `Clear all caches`, and I try to reload the page, it won't stop loading.
I wonder what is going wrong.

Comment: First, try deleting the `services.yml` and rebuild the cache again to see if you can get the page to load.  If so, you know you copied the file incorrectly.  If not, assuming you are working in a local dev environment and security is not a concern, try adding `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` to **settings.php** to get a more detailed error.

Comment: I already had that config value in my settings.php,  Also I retried it in your order and it works now!